# Platform-dependent Docker images - how to?

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, docker

I have installed Docker on a Raspberry Pi, but usually I am working on OS X on a MacBook Pro. So since the first is ARM-based, while the latter is X86-based, I have a problem when it comes to Docker images: They are not compatible.

Is there a way to build a Docker image using a Dockerfile on OS X that is meant to run on the ARM platform?

Comment: Building is done on the docker daemon. Configure your docker-client to connect to the raspberry pi as long as you wish to build docker arm images.

Comment: I explicitly asked whether it is possible to *build a Docker image using a Dockerfile on OS X* for ARM, so building on the Pi itself is not an option.

Comment: Yes and I told you, that it's possible to have the docker file on os x. You never said, that you don't want the pi to build your image. You only wanted the dockerfile to be on the Mac. Why is this no option?

Comment: Reading *Is there a way to build a Docker image using a Dockerfile on OS X* as "I only want the Dockerfile to be on OS X" seems pretty picky to me, but anyway… it is no option, because I want to have *one* build process on my machine for multiple platforms, including Pi, no matter whether I am connected to the Pi or not.

Comment: Picky or specific, whatever. But its also possible to build arm images with x86 and qemu-arm. I will post the link later. But I think if you want to build for multiple ABIs and OS you need different workflows/Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, you can prepare your Dockerfile on OSX and once you are happy with it, you can build it on your ARM machine.

The trusted build from index.docker.io might support this feature in the future.

Comment: Regarding the "trusted build feature in the future" - is this just speculation, or do you know more than I do :-)?

Comment: I am core dev at Docker. I want it and I try to push toward it. No warranty though. We'll know more when the registry will support multiple arch.

Comment: any update in 2 more years since the last one?  I have seen using a statically linked QEMU binary to run things in an already created binary, but it is possible to use that to build in a container with qemu, and copy the output to an existing arm container?  What about apt-get updates?

Answer (score 2):

Docker for Mac supports cross-platform builds out of the box via the `buildx` command. I've used this command to build x86-64 images from my ARM MacBook.

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 .
```

I believe you should be able to target Raspberry Pi 4 via the `linux/arm64` platform. See [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images) for more details.